# Custom Tag for Hiding Views in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a custom tag in Django (or written by somebody else) that supports displaying/hiding views based on user roles and permissions?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "hiding" views? Preventing a user from accessing them?

Check out [the `permission_required` decorator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator)

Comment: @pokiman: You're welcome. You can press the upvote and checkmark if it solves your problem :)